# Github and plink not working on 1 repo

Tags: git, github, plink

Hi i use git and keePassAgent to save me SSH keys. It works fine but 2 days ago I create new repository in github and when I cloned it, do some code and I want push changed to server, but git not want use the plink, only openssh. I will only add that I have 2 repositories (bitbucket) and plink works fine.

My problems is that on that repo git (version 1.8.3-preview20130601) not want use plink. I have GIT_SSH set to c:\plink.exe and file in that disk, in git bash:

```
$ echo $GIT_SSH
C:\plink.exe
$ $GIT_SSH
PuTTY Link: command-line connection utility
Release 0.62
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
   ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
Options:
[...]
```

Ok so plink work,

```
$ $GIT_SSH git@github.com
Using username "git".
Server refused to allocate pty
Hi myGithubLogin! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But when I execute:

```
$ ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myWinLogin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

or git push origin master in repo git not want use plink, why ???
Thanks for you answers I use `Windows 7, git version 1.8.3-preview20130601 and plink 0.62`